# ¿Pasar un valor a un Textview que esta en otro Layout que no se carga en el setContentView()?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

tengo un problema al enviar un texto a un TextView, el problema es que el TextView al cual quiero enviarle el texto esta en un Layout que no se carga en el setContentView().

Este es el nav_header_main de donde intento tomar el TextView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cuentalog"
    />

**<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ususesion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Usuario" />**
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Usuario@seccion15.org.mx"
    />
```

Y asi es la vista de la aplicacion, en el TextView que dice usario quiero mostrar el Nombre del usario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la clase desde donde quiero mandar ese dato, el codigo que:

```
package com.example.enriq.persistencia_en_android_enrique_espinosa;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

    public class pincipal extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        View view;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_pincipal);

            // se tiene que importar la clase v7 para
            // que no muestre error al instancear la clase Toolbar
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            //si la siguiente linea de codigo marca error es por que no ha implementado el metodo
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            **LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);
            String nombreArchivo = getIntent().getExtras().getString(MainActivity.FILE_KEY);
            TextView txtusario = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ususesion);
            Toast.makeText(this,"el archivo se llama: "+nombreArchivo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {
                File archivo = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), nombreArchivo);
                ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(archivo));
                Usuario usuario = (Usuario) input.readObject();
                input.close();
                txtusario.setText(usuario.toString());
                Toast.makeText(this,"el usario que debe aparecer es: "+usuario.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }catch (IOException e){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al abrir el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al cargar la clase Usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }**

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed(){
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }else{
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
            //este metodo es para obtener el id del menu de los
            //tres puntos
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if(id == R.id.exportar){
               onClickRadio(view);
            }else if(id == R.id.sesion){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            //con este codigo recuperamos el id del item seleccionado en el
            //navigationdrawer para poder seleccionarlo o cambiar de fragmento
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if(id == R.id.iniciotap){
                //Traemos al fragmento de inicio
                /*fragment_home  home = new fragment_home();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                //vamos a sustitur el contenedor del activity main por un nuevo fragment
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.exp, home).commit();
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                toolbar.setSubtitle("Inicio");*/
            }else if(id == R.id.noticiastap){
                //Traemos al fragmento de noticias
               /*noticias_generales noticiasg = new noticias_generales();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                //vamos a sustitur el contenedor del activity main por un nuevo fragment
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.exp, noticiasg).commit();
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                toolbar.setSubtitle("Noticias Generales");*/
            }
            //Este codigo nos permite mostrar que menu esta seleccionado
            //para poder identificar que menu esta en uso
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }

        public void onClickRadio(View view){
            Dialogo.listaRadio(this, view).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow... ¿Y dónde se carga entonces? ¿Podrías mostrar el código donde usas ese `TextView` al cual le quieres asignar el valor?

Comment: Nose que tantos datos necesitas , pero puedes usar una clase STATICA y alli guardar los datos y luego desde tu actividad recuperarlos y cargarlos donde quieras

Comment: El textView esta en un nav_header_main, este es un Layout nadamas por que estoy usando Navigation Drawer.

Comment: @Kikehatake todos estos detalles que comentas deben agregarse a la pregunta para que los usuarios de la comunidad puedan fácilmente saber que es lo que deseas. Ver [ask].

Comment: Este es el nav_header_main de donde stoy intentando tomar el TextView

Comment: Arriba añadi el codigo faltante

Comment: Kike, aquí tú tienes una referencia al `TextView`: **`TextView txtusario = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ususesion);`** y aquí, tú intentas setearle algo: **`txtusario.setText(usuario.toString());`** Entonces, **¿cuál es el problema en sí?** ¿No muestra nada el `TextView`? Puede que `usuario.toString()` esté en blanco o que el código no pase por ahí... ¿Has probado a poner algo arbitrario como: `txtusario.setText("Texto de prueba");` para ver qué ocurre?

Comment: si, el problema es que no se esta mostrando, en la clase que puse arriba estoy usando el codigo para llamar al layout que contiene el TextView, pero no se visualisa ningun cambio, si pongo el ejemplo que tu me mensionas de colocar algo asi: txtusario.setText("Texto de prueba"); <<Tampoco funciona>> no se visualiza ningun cambio

Comment: te deje un ejemplo abajo me cuentas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

busca la referencia del `TextView` de esta forma:

```
navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nombrePerfil);
```

ejemplo completo:

```
//Obtiene referencia de TextView usado como header.
TextView profileName = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nombrePerfil);    
//Asigna texto a TextView.
profileName.setText("Texto de prueba");
```

Comment: Lo estoy intentando pero no entiendo del todo como le puedo mandar el setText();

Comment: te actualize la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo logre con tu ayuda

Comment: de nada Kike , suerte

Answer (score 0):

Estoy realizando una aplicación y me encontré con un caso un poco similar, yo quería actualizar un TextView de mi Actividad main desde otra actividad, el valor que insertaba en el TextView se guardaba en una Clase modelo .Java, el valor cambiaba lo que no podía era actualizar dicho valor en el textView, la solución que encontré fue realizar el setText del TextView dentro del metodo OnResume.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    numCarrito.setText(LocalUser.getUsuarioShoppingCart().size()+"");                  
}
```

Así este se actualiza y ejecuta esta línea de código al volver a la actividad main.
Espero les halla servido, Muchas gracias.